# OS X Yosemite Git Editor Not Working Correctly

Tags: git, macos, editor

I'm having an odd problem with git and my editor. I've been all over Stack Overflow and I have been unable to find a similar problem.

When executing `git` commit I'm getting the following error:

```
-w: -w: command not found
error: There was a problem with the editor ' -w'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

I've tried emacs, VIM, and Atom, setting them in the global `.gitconfig` file as follows:

editor =     `/usr/bin/emacs`

I've also set the editor in my `.bash_profile` as follows:

```
export EDITOR=emacs
```

I receive the same error using any editor that I choose.

All the editors work correctly otherwise, as does git.

I'd appreciate any help solving this problem.

Comment: What does `git config --get core.editor` tell you?

Answer (score 1):

You may check all your editor variables:

```
git config --global core.editor emacs
```

Or:

```
git config --global --edit
```

You should configure the file as follow:

```
[core]
    editor = emacs
```

Check also the local (current repository) and system configurations:

```
git config --local --edit
git config --system --edit
```

You most likely have a bad `-w` editor somewhere.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Unfortunately none of those commands resolved the issue. The first seemed to execute correctly. The second returned the same "-w..." error. "git config --local --edit" returned a fatal error - '.git/': No such file or directory . The last returned the same "-w..." error. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Sorry for the `--edit` option which cannot work precisely because of your problem :p. You have to locate manually your configuration files: `/etc/gitconfig` (for `--system`, you must be `root` to edit it), `~/.gitconfig` (for `--global`, in your home) and `<repo>/.git/config` (for `--local`, but you must be located a git repository to make it work, e.g. `cd <repo>`, that's why it didn't work for you). When you find the line with `editor = ' -v'`, delete it. I think the problem is in `/etc/gitconfig` or `~/.gitconfig`. Waiting for your diagnostic...

Comment: You can ask git which variables are set: `git config --list`. You should find `editor` with ` -v` value. Then, filter by configuration file: `git config --global --list`. If `editor` is there, just type: `git config --global --unset core.editor`. Try with `--system` if it does not work with `--global`. Use `man git-config` to find others tricks if needed ;-) The `FILES` section show where git stores configuration files. Note that git will search in the `GIT_EDITOR` environment variable if no `core.editor` is set. Try `echo $GIT_EDITOR` to check if the problem is not here.

Comment: Thank you @jbaptperez for your help. I've resolved the issue. I'd installed the bash-it framework some time ago and one of the plugins that was enabled contained the line that was changing the editor.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been resolved. I had installed the bash-it framework and a plugin was changing my $GIT_EDITOR value. I removed the plugin and my system is working correctly.